# pjsip shows zero round-trip time (RTT)

Tags: c, time, sip, voip, pjsip

A product I'm working on uses [pjsip and friends](http://www.pjsip.org/) to do some VOIP calls between machines. Statistics about the call are retrieved using [pjsua_call_get_stream_stat](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga45e4252f1aa36f6c1f94d2e3497cdbbc), which successfully returns with lots of metrics. However, the round-trip time data stored in [stat](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__stream__stat.htm).[rtcp](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__rtcp__stat.htm).[rtt](http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/structpj__math__stat.htm) is always zero. Given that I'm making calls from Seattle to Singapore, this is certainly not correct.

I traced how the `rtt` struct is set, and it is done by `pjsua_call_get_stream_stat` via [pjmedia_stream_get_stat](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__STRM.htm#ga10eef122bc961cead72f983ced0f6241), which is just a thinly-wrapped `memcpy` from the stream's `stat` struct to the destination one.

The *really* weird thing is that I used GDB to set watchpoints on the stream's `stat` struct (i.e. `stream->rtcp.stat`) and its member variables, and lo and behold, the only time those addresses are written to is when they're being initialized to zero.

Why is RTT info never being written? Is there some configuration that could be messed up, even if the rest of the data returned from `pjsua_call_get_stream_stat` looks good?

Answer (score 0):

This may be your NAT device blocking all RCTP RR packets. You can try to enable STUN, or use public IP addresses on both sides.